# ключевой объект HashMap

Tags: java

Что будет, если попытаться вставить в HashMap уже имеющийся в ней ключевой объект?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все зависит от того переопределены ли в объекте-ключе методы `hashcode` и `equals`

HashMap сначала по хешкоду вычисляет корзину, потом проходит по элементам корзины и если встречает подходящий хешкод, то проверяет равность объектов через `equals`.

Значит, если хоть один из методов в объекте-ключе не переопределен, то поиск закончится ничем. По `Object.hashCode()` может и найдется нужная корзина (случайно), но `equals` очно даст false, если это 2 объекта с разными ссылками

---

Если же оба метода переопределены, то как сказали выше значение по этому ключу просто перезатрется.

Есть один интересный момент: метод `Map.put(K key, V value)` возвращает предыдущее значение по данному ключу, если его не было вернет `null`. Иногда это полезно.

Answer (score 0):

Eсли попытаться повторно вставить ключ в HashMap, он заменит старый, поскольку класс HashMap не допускает дублирующихся ключей. А тот же ключ означает такой же хэш-код, так что он попадет в то же место в хэш-сегменте.
https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/404-khitrihe-voprosih-po-java-kotorihe-chasto-zadajut-na-sobesedovanijakh-